# Maximizing Area With Right Triangles

Tags: geometry, area

I looked through this site and the internet for a while and found some related problems, but not with my particular constraints. The problem is:

> Given a $n*m$ rectangle, cut four congruent right triangles using the corners as the right angles. What is the maximum area that each triangle can have?

Let me explain a bit further: 
This is an example illustration to help with the visual side of things 
[image]

You can see that the four lines have created four (theoretically) identical right triangles each with the same area. What I am wondering is how we could maximize 
this area, while still having each triangle be congruent.

**My attempts:**

 I thought that if we placed the triangles' vertices halfway across each side, such that the $4$ hypotenuses created a rectangle with the empty space. It would look like this: 
[image]

This would mean that each triangle has area $\frac{1}{8}nm$

For some reason, half of me feels as if this is the solution while the other half feels as if there is something I am overlooking. If anyone could provide some aid as to the correctness of my solution. Many thanks.

Comment: Do all the triangle have to be congruent?

Comment: Yes, they all have to be congruent, otherwise you cut just cut one huge triangle with the diagonal as the hypotenuse.

Comment: Of course if you change the corner requirements slightly to say that each corner of the rectangle is a vertex of exactly one of the congruent triangles, you can get arbitrarily close to using the whole rectangle.

Comment: FYI: Regarding "if we placed the triangles' vertices halfway across each side (of the m*n rectangle with $m \ne n$), such that the 4 hypotenuses created a rectangle with the empty space", that empty space is a rhombus.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am able to understand your line of thinking is correct. If you call the two sides of the triangle which aren't the hypotenuse $a$ and $b$. Then the area of each triangle is given by $\frac{ab}{2}$. Increasing a, or increasing b will increase the area of the triangle.

Therefore we seek the maximum value of $a$ and $b$. The only limiting factor is that (without loss of generality) $2a\leqslant n$ and $2b \leqslant m$. Therefore we take $a = n/2$ and $b = m/2$. 
This gives $area = \frac{mn}{8}$ as you said.

Comment: Or the condition that $a+b=S \leq L$ for a square. But this gives the same result. That maximum occurs occurs when $a=b=S/2$, and taking $S=L$ gives the max out of all these possibilities.